# Google Play Game - Is it possible to limit the number of plays per day to free users?

Tags: google-play-games

I have written a game. I would like to go with the AdMob based monitization. There will be a paid option of No Ads.

However, I would also like to limit the number of plays a person can do in a day for the free version to maybe 2 or 3, unless they have paid for the No Ads option where they can have unlimited plays.

How could this be done?

Shared preferences or any data will be deleted if a person uninstalls the game then re-installs. I do not want a database option on my server. So it has to be some file or something on the phone itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information has to be stored somewhere.

- if you want it to survive uninstall then re-install, it can't be stored on the client
- you say you don't want to store it on your server

There is only one place left, someone else's server. There are lots of options to this, but one would be using Google Play Games servers. For example, you could use the [Saved Games API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames). However, it is counted against the users Google Drive quota so they can delete it. You could also use some other provider like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).